# Django Middleware

Tags: python, django

How can I do, whole urls for my site available only for register user.
I use Middleware, but this class doesn't work

I use Django==2.1.4

```
class MyAuthorization:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response

    def process_request(request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')  # or http response
        return None
```

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'myapp.middleware.MyAuthorization',
```

]

Comment: Can you please post the order of your middleware? Is your custom middleware after `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware`?

Comment: Also, what "doesn't work" about your custom middleware. Are you getting an error?

Comment: I posted at the end of the list MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
     'myapp.middleware.MyAuthorization',
]

Comment: Ok, add your list of middleware to your question too for context please.

Comment: If you put a debug `print("I am here")` statement in the `process_request` function, does it print to your server console?

Comment: I don't have any error, just nothing happened. My url works like no any middleware

Comment: Does the print statement execute (i.e. Is your middle-ware function being called at all) when a request occurs?

Comment: Where can I see debug console. Is it the same console where i typed runserver in Pycharm?

Comment: Yes it is. If you do a print statement in your code it should go there.

Comment: I didn't see any message in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `process_request` method in your middleware class will never get called - there is nothing in Django that calls such a method. You need to perform that logic in the `__call__` method itself, before calling `get_response()` - something like this:

```
class MyAuthorization:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:  # Note, this is a property, not a method
            if not request.path == '/':
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Note the second `if` statement - `if not request.path == '/'` - this is to ensure that you don't get an infinite redirect. You probably need to use similar logic to exclude your login views from this check, otherwise a logged-out user would never be able to reach it.

Comment: I tried do this, but it's not working, its continuous redirected.

Comment: You need to exclude your login/home page URLs from the check.

Comment: I've updated the answer to illustrate how you can exclude specific URLs from the check.

Answer (score 0):

As @solarissmoke states, you should use `__call__` instead of `process_request`.

```
def __call__(self, request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Also if the user is not authenticated you are just redirecting to '/', that can give the impression nothing is happening.

Perhaps you should redirect to whatever is your login view.